# How to assign empty array to dynamic property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, properties

Trying to add empty array to dynamic property, then fill the array dynamically. Contents of array are unknown until runtime and could be nothing.

Here is the code which does work in jsfiddle but not working in my app - so I'll have to dig deeper.

```
var ref = {s:5, d:{a:100, b:50}}

bigObject = {}

bigObject.object = {};

for (var i = 1;i<10;i++){
    var n = 's'+i
    bigObject.object[n] = []
}

bigObject.object['s'+ref.s].push(ref.d);

console.log(bigObject)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle ? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It works just fine. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for quick replies. You are correct. The code is OK. Something else wrong in my app I guess.

Comment: And from now on this newcomer will be checking in jsfiddle first.